# Processing sketch won't display modified image on screen

Tags: image-processing, processing

I am making a sketch which does the following:

Resizes a large image to fit it into a `800 x 600` screen.

displays the image

Applies some effects when keys are pressed

Display the image back on the screen and print a little `Done` message

Everything works fine expect that it does not display the image back properly.

Here is the black and white effect:

```
void blackAndWhite() {
  loadPixels();
  for (int i = 0;i < img.pixels.length;i++) {
    int pixel = img.pixels[i];

    // println("Working on pixel " + i + " out of " + img.pixels.length); 

    int red = (int) red(pixel);
    int green = (int) green(pixel);
    int blue = (int) blue(pixel);

    /*
     * Luminosity Method.
     */
    //      red = (int) (red * 0.21);
    //      green = (int) (green * 0.71);
    //      blue = (int) (blue * 0.07);

    /*
     * Average Method
     */
    //  float avg = (int) (red + green + blue / 3);
    //  red = green = blue = (int) avg;

    /*
     * Lightness Method
     */
    int mostProminent = max(red, green, blue);
    int leastProminent = min(red, green, blue);
    int avg = (int) ((mostProminent + leastProminent) / 2);
    red = green = blue = avg;

    pixel = color(red, green, blue);
    img.pixels[i] = pixel;
  }
  println("Done");
  updatePixels();
  image(img, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2, calculatedWidth, calculatedHeight);
}
```

However, only the colored image is displayed :(
I know the algorithm works cause I have tried it on other images (not using this sketch).
**What is going wrong?**

Comment: Not sure if this makes a difference, but is it safe/sensible to have variables red, green and blue with the same names as functions red, green and blue?

Comment: @Zaphod Yeh. It's quite OK. I have tried this algorithm in another sketch and it works fine :) If I call `blackAndWhite` in `setup()`, I get a BnW image. Just not from `keyPressed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works fine:

```
PImage img;

void setup () {
  img = loadImage ("img.png");
  size(img.width, img.height);
}

void draw () {
  image(img, 0, 0);
}

void keyReleased () {
  blackAndWhite();
}

void blackAndWhite() {

  img.loadPixels();
  for (int i = 0;i < img.pixels.length;i++) {
    int pixel = img.pixels[i];

    // println("Working on pixel " + i + " out of " + img.pixels.length); 

    int red = (int) red(pixel);
    int green = (int) green(pixel);
    int blue = (int) blue(pixel);

    /*
     * Luminosity Method.
     */
    //      red = (int) (red * 0.21);
    //      green = (int) (green * 0.71);
    //      blue = (int) (blue * 0.07);

    /*
     * Average Method
     */
    //  float avg = (int) (red + green + blue / 3);
    //  red = green = blue = (int) avg;

    /*
     * Lightness Method
     */
    int mostProminent = max(red, green, blue);
    int leastProminent = min(red, green, blue);
    int avg = (int) ((mostProminent + leastProminent) / 2);
    red = green = blue = avg;

    pixel = color(red, green, blue);
    img.pixels[i] = pixel;
  }
  println("Done");
  img.updatePixels();
}
```

My guess is that you either forgot to write **img**.loadPixels() instead of loadPixels(), or there was something wrong in sketch's **draw()** method.

Comment: what does mere `loadPixels()` do ?

Comment: The function loadPixels() calls the 1d-array of pixel color values of your sketch window. Your sketch called window's pixels, but then you used the **dot operator** – img.someMethod() – to access image's pixels. Basically, you loaded window's pixels, but then wrote instructions to modify unloaded image's pixels.